# A local IP address (RFC 1918) on my network that is not ... local ..

Tags: networking, ip

I've noticed an IP address today on my network (192.168.15.1) which when visited actually goes to a page that has a router webconfig page (Not **my** router)

The puzzling thing is that i tried `traceroute 192.168.15.1` which said that the distance between me and that host is 9 hops, whereas the distance between me and any other computer on my home network is 2 hops away
(My computer --> Router --> Host)

Can someone please explain what's going on here ?